# Error on update elasticsearch php "document_missing_exception"

Tags: php, elasticsearch

I'm using Elasticsearch with PHP and after the required data mapping. I inserted the data via insert function as seen below:

```
public function insertNode ($event_id) {
    global $conn1;
    $client = $this->elasticclient;
    $params = null;

    $stmt = "SELECT
                 events.event_id,
                 events.event_title,
                 events.event_details,
                 DATE_FORMAT(events.added_date,'%d-%m-%Y') AS added_date 
                 FROM events
                 WHERE events.event_id = $event_id";

    $query = $conn1->prepare($stmt);
    $query->execute();
    $rows = $query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    foreach ($rows as $row) {
        $params = [
            'index' => 'eventree',
            'type'  => 'events',
            'id'    => $row['event_id'],
            'body'  => [
                'EVENT_TITLE'   => $row['event_title'],
                'EVENT_DETAILS' => $row['event_details'],
                'START_TIME'    => $row['start_time'],
                'ADDED_DATE'    => $row['added_date'],
                'STATUS'        => $row['status']
            ]
        ];
    }

    $responses = $client->index($params);

    return true;
}
```

below you can see how I update data:

```
public function updateNode($event_id) {
    global $conn1;
    $client = $this->elasticclient;
    $params = null;

    $stmt = "SELECT
                 events.event_id,
                 events.event_title,
                 events.event_details,
                 events.status,
                 DATE_FORMAT(events.added_date,'%d-%m-%Y') AS added_date 
                 FROM events
                 WHERE events.event_id = $event_id";

    $query = $conn1->prepare($stmt);
    $query->execute();
    $rows = $query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    foreach ($rows as $row) {
        $params = [
            'index' => 'eventree',
            'type' => 'events',
            'id' => $row['event_id'],
            'body' => [
                'doc' => [
                    'EVENT_TITLE' => $row['event_title'],
                    'EVENT_DETAILS' => $row['event_details'],
                    'START_TIME' => $row['start_time'],
                    'ADDED_DATE' => $row['added_date'],
                    'STATUS' => $row['status']
        ]]];
    }

    $responses = $client->update($params);
    return true;
}
```

The problem is that the update process won't accept ids larger than 9, although there are records with ids greter than number 9. This is the error I get after running the update proccess:

```
{
"error": "{\"error\":{\"root_cause\":[{\"type\":\"document_missing_exception\",\"reason\":\"[events][10]: document missing\",\"index_uuid\":\"6l5vWeLLSb6CvcCsqTws9g\",\"shard\":\"1\",\"index\":\"eventree\"}],\"type\":\"document_missing_exception\",\"reason\":\"[events][10]: document missing\",\"index_uuid\":\"6l5vWeLLSb6CvcCsqTws9g\",\"shard\":\"1\",\"index\":\"eventree\"},\"status\":404}"
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your php code is wrong, you loop `$rows` and override `$params` variable all the time!

Comment: thanks Thomas Decaux , the solution is very simple , I put ( $responses = $client->index($params); and $responses = $client->update($params); ) in foreach block

Comment: Always good to have someone else looking at code :-) btw you should use bulk API to group queries

Answer (score 0):

the correct code

```
    public function insertNode($event_id) {
global $conn1;
$client = $this->elasticclient;
$params = null;

$stmt = "SELECT
             events.event_id,
             events.event_title,
             events.event_details,
             DATE_FORMAT(events.added_date,'%d-%m-%Y') AS added_date 
             FROM events
             WHERE events.event_id = $event_id";

$query = $conn1->prepare($stmt);
$query->execute();
$rows = $query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

foreach ($rows as $row) {
    $params = [
        'index' => 'eventree',
        'type' => 'events',
        'id' => $row['event_id'],
        'body' => [
            'EVENT_TITLE' => $row['event_title'],
            'EVENT_DETAILS' => $row['event_details'],
            'START_TIME' => $row['start_time'],
            'ADDED_DATE' => $row['added_date'],
            'STATUS' => $row['status']
    ]];
    $responses = $client->index($params);
}

return true;
```

}

```
public function updateNode($event_id) {
global $conn1;
$client = $this->elasticclient;
$params = null;

$stmt = "SELECT
             events.event_id,
             events.event_title,
             events.event_details,
             events.status,
             DATE_FORMAT(events.added_date,'%d-%m-%Y') AS added_date 
             FROM events
             WHERE events.event_id = $event_id";

$query = $conn1->prepare($stmt);
$query->execute();
$rows = $query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

foreach ($rows as $row) {
    $params = [
        'index' => 'eventree',
        'type' => 'events',
        'id' => $row['event_id'],
        'body' => [
            'doc' => [
                'EVENT_TITLE' => $row['event_title'],
                'EVENT_DETAILS' => $row['event_details'],
                'START_TIME' => $row['start_time'],
                'ADDED_DATE' => $row['added_date'],
                'STATUS' => $row['status']
    ]]];

$responses = $client->update($params);
}

return true;
```

}